# Restrict users to their home directory

Tags: server, bash

I'm setting up beginner CTF (Capture the flag) in a Linux environment.
I will have questions that will tell the user to run specific commands.

The issue I'm having is restricting the user to a directory and only being able to run certain commands.

For example
Players need to change the directory and then use "ls" to find the flag and complete the challenge.

But I don't want a player to see other directories in the server or people able to cd where there not supposed to go.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Investigate the possibility to use a [restricted shell](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/The-Restricted-Shell.html) for the users. Together with modifying PATH to specify a directory wich contains only commands that you allow your users to run (you may create such a directory and just put symlinks or hardlinks to the original commands there) it may give you what you need.

Answer (score 0):

I have 2 possible solutions:

1. Give the ctf's user permissions only to their home directory, you will need a different user for every challenge. every time they will try to cd out of the directory they will be denied.

I found a different post that suggests using the adduser command:

```
adduser --home/restricted/directory restricted_user
```

https://superuser.com/questions/149404/create-an-ssh-user-who-only-has-permission-to-access-specific-folders

2. Use docker and run each level in a different environment.

hope this helps!

Comment: Hey Roey, Your first option is exactly what I want but I need help setting it up, any clue?

Comment: I edited my post to show a possible solution to how you might want to do that.